# Looping array from input and getting all matches

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

I'm trying to loop through an array of items and see if any of those match then show them. Well if I type in any character they all show.

```
(sensitive == false ? RegExp('^'+this.value,'i').test(source[i]) : RegExp('^'+this.value).test(source[i]) )
```

this is my condition, though if the `this.value` = `a` every single item in the array (`source[i]`) shows up. Is there a way to make this more strict?

**EXAMPLE**

if array is (using jquery autocomplete example array)

```
var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
];
```

```
element.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    var dd = document.getElementById('fake_dropdown');
    for (i = 0; i < availableTags.length; i++) {
        var li;
        if ((sensitive == false ? RegExp('^' + this.value, 'i').test(availableTags[i]) : RegExp('^' + this.value).test(availableTags[i]))) {
            li = document.getElementById('auto_id_' + (i + 1));
            li.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            li = document.getElementById('auto_id_' + (i + 1));
            li.style.display = "none";
        }
        var liLoop = dd.getElementsByTagName('li');
        for (var j = 0; j < liLoop.length; j++) {
            if (liLoop[j].style.display == "block") break;
            else dd.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}, false);
```

**UPDATED MORE CODE**

All these show up. Why is this? Also why is `BACKSPACE` not considered to be a keypress, for it doesn't reevaluate the condition if I click backspace.

Comment: can you share more code on how the result is obtained

Comment: Yeah hold on I will add more. It's just very very lengthy

Comment: and the html also - if possible create the case in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZUY2n/1/

Comment: @EasyBB - Don't use `keypress`. `keypress` will not be fired when a special key is pressed. (Also the keycode returned by the event is wrong too.)

Comment: I'll do one better and place the whole darn code in there. It's a vanilla JavaScript only autoComplete. http://jsfiddle.net/kH9d3/1/  scroll all the way to the bottom to see the initiated code and half way to see the focus function. Sometimes these things fly over my head after working hours and hours on a code.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I didn't even use a `keyCode` or `e.which` so don't know what you mean on that, and ok so no keypress if special characters are wanted.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZUY2n/3/

Comment: the keypress event is not fired for non printable characters like delete, backspace etc

Comment: @ArunPJohny works for a not other characters though.

Comment: New Fiddle from what @ArunPJohny suggested http://jsfiddle.net/kH9d3/2/

Comment: @EasyBB sorry what did you mean by `works for a not other characters though`?

Comment: I tried b and c and it didn't work only for a

Comment: @EasyBB it is not working because of the `dd.style.display = 'none'` see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2X42T/2/

Comment: Please add to answer so I can up vote Thanks so much I knew something was silly here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See

```
el.addEventListener('focus', function (e) {
    lastIndex = this;
    if (typeof focus == 'function') focus.call(this, this);
}, false);
//use keyup handler since keypress will not be fired for unprintable characters
//don't register the handler inside the focus handler since it can cause multiple event registrations
el.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    var dd = document.getElementById('fake_dropdown'),
        items = 0;
    var top, left, height, width, bottom;

    var term = this.value,
        //move this out out the for loop
        regex = (sensitive == false ? new RegExp('^' + this.value, 'i') : new RegExp('^' + this.value));

    for (i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        var li = document.getElementById('auto_id_' + (i + 1));
        if (regex.test(availableTags[i])) {
            li.style.display = "block";
            items++;
        } else {
            li.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    if (items == 0) {
        dd.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        top = el.offsetTop
        left = el.offsetLeft;
        height = el.offsetHeight;
        width = el.offsetWidth;
        bottom = top + height;
        dd.style.left = left + 'px';
        dd.style.top = bottom + 'px';
        dd.style.width = width + 'px';
        dd.style.display = "block";
    }
}, false);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2X42T/)